# How to install: Onboard Intel GPU (-> x-server), Dedicated Nvidia GPU (-> cuda computations only)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, xorg, cuda

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 system. If I install nvidia drivers

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-430
```

I can see using `nvidia-smi` that the memory, needed for the x-server gets allocated on my nvidia-gpu (RTX 2080), althought the displays are connected to the onboard graphics card.
I want to avoid this, as I need the nvidia-gpu and it's entire memory for CUDA computations.

So I read that I need to

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

and then install the drivers using the `*.run`-file but without installing OpenGl libraries:

```
# Switch off X-Server
[Ctrl + Alt + F1 ]
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.40.run --no-open-gl-files
```

This however fails with the message:

```
 ERROR: Unable to load the 'nvidia-drm' kernel module.
```

Any idea how to fix this or a comprehensive tutorial for my case?

PS: I also tried blacklisting some of the drivers as recommended in other threads. So my `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf/` has the following additional lines meanwhile:

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
blacklist vga16fb
blacklist rivafb
#blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv
blacklist amd76_edac
options nouveau modeset=0
```

However this didn't have any effect, even after rebooting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working: I had to reinstall Ubuntu (couldn't make it work otherwise). In the fresh installation I first add the following lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
options nouveau modeset=0
```

-> reboot

then

```
# Switch off X-Server
[Ctrl + Alt + F1 ]
sudo service gdm stop # "gdm" for gnome / "ligthdm" for unity
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.40.run --no-open-gl-files --no-drm
```

during installation:

```
-> update xorg.conf?: "no"
```

Reboot after installation.

The important part is here the `--no-open-gl-files --no-drm` options. Especially `drm` (direct rendering manager) apparently is guilty of using the Nvidia GPU's memory.